# How to get old historic data for a year from Flightradar24?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airports, history

While searching for historic flight data I came across Flightradar24.

According to them they do not provide any API. I found a [link URL](https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/flight/list.json?query=AI101&fetchBy=flight&page=1&limit=100), but this only provides one week's data for AI101.

I'm planning  to take a business plan so could anyone help me in how to generate a token to be added to this URL to get 1 year of data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Historic flight data](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89543/historic-flight-data)

Comment: To make commercial use of flightradar24 data, or burden their servers (if not a one-off), I would contact them first. The same applies to any provider of data. There is a separate stackexchange website for questions about the technical details of interacting with web-based service providers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an API, not travel.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using FlightRadar, you would probably be best to go directly to the source - [https://www.adsbexchange.com/](https://www.adsbexchange.com).

They offer fully [historical data sets](https://www.adsbexchange.com/data/#) with a decent API.